# How to know which file sourced a particular file

Tags: linux, bash, dotfiles

Ubuntu 16.04; zsh; oh my zsh; KDE

I have many dotfiles like `.bashrc`, `.commonrc`, `.zshrc` sourcing each other. Say I want to stop sourcing a particular file `.bash_docker`. Is there a way to know which file sourced it?

I figured it out through manual examination, but it happens quite often... It seems like `source` has no man page or help option.

Comment: https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/caller perhaps?

Comment: Add this line at the beginning of `.bash_docker`: `((${#BASH_SOURCE[@]} > 1)) && echo "I'm sourced from ${BASH_SOURCE[1]}" >> /tmp/bash_docker.log` and check the file `/tmp/bash_docker.log`

Comment: I doubt my suggestion will work if your current shell is `zsh`. You should look for a solution in `zsh`, not in `bash`, in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try printing this in your target script

```
echo "This script sourced from : ${BASH_SOURCE[1]}"
```

Here are the bash variables of interest for reference
https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html

Comment: Turns out I have to use bash instead of zsh. Works well!!